# Rails 3 passing data with has_one association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-associations, has-one

I am building a job board where workers can bid on jobs and bosses can accept a single bid for each job they have, creating an "assignment". On the job show page, already constructed bids can be accepted by a boss. Among other things, I have the following associations:

```
Job:
  has_many :bids
  has_many :assignments, :through => :bids

Bid:
  has_one :assignment
  belongs_to :job

Assignment:
  belongs_to :bid
  has_one :job, :through => :bid
```

In the Job Show Page: (form for a boss to accept a bid)

```
<%= form_for :assignments, :url => '/assignments' do |f| %>

  <%= f.submit "Accept Bid", class: "btn btn-mini" %>
<% end %>
```

In the Job Controller:

```
Show Action:
  @job.bids.each { |bid| bid.build_assignment }
```

In the Assignment Controller:

```
Create Action:
  @bid = Bid.find(params[:bid_id])
  @assignment = @bid.build_assignment(params[:assignment])
  @assignment.save
```

As you can see, I am trying to build an assignment through association with a bid. Questions:

1) When I click "accept bid" (form above), rails displays an error indicating the bid cannot be found (in the assignment controller create action). Why?

2) I also tried doing: <%= f.hidden_field :bid_id %> in the form and changing the Assignment create action to: @assignment = Assignment.new(params[:assignment]), but now the assignment object won't save because apparently there is no bid_id.

Comment: Are you sure you have bid_id in the form as a hidden field?

Comment: For security reasons, is there any way to avoid putting the bid_id in the form and instead create through associations?